# How to compare these two files in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I have these file namely test1.csv which has data like

```
Paris
London
New York
Brisbane
```

and test2.csv which has same data but different order

```
London
Paris
Brisbane
New York
```

I'm comparing these 2 files and if they're equal I'm updating a flag. But how to compare these 2 files.?

**EDIT:**
If the file has numeric data like

```
0025
0013
0566
```

what approach to be followed to sort it in ascending order.?

Comment: It is not clear whether your question is how to sort or how to compare. If it is comparing, why does it matter to sort in ascending or descending order?

Comment: If you have `0025` in one file and `25` in another - should they be considered to be identical or not? What do you want the result of the comparison to be - a boolean or a count of number of lines different or a list of the differences or something else?

Comment: Hi Ed sorry for the late reply, We will always get the same value in both the files actually so if it is 0025 in first file it will be the same in second file but the order may be different. :)

Answer (score 5):

Sort then diff the files:

```
diff <(sort test1.csv) <(sort test2.csv)
```

Comment: Hi if it's a numeric based files like 0012,0013,0045 can I use sort.?

Comment: @user2647888: yes, you can use `sort` regardless of what the files contain (as long as it is vaguely textual, so there are a reasonable supply of line breaks; it is pointless sorting a 1-line JSON file, even if it is 10 GiB).  What matters is that the same sort criteria are used on both files, so related entries will be sorted in the same sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can first sort files and then compare them:

```
sort file1.csv
```

However, The above approach sorts a file line by line. If your content is in one line (e.g. there is comma separated numerical values in one line), then you might want to put them in separate lines first. For example:

```
cat > file1 $ `0025, 0013, 0566` 

cat > file2 $ `0013, 0025, 0566`
```

and you try sorting them, it will not work:

```
sort file1 : $ `0025, 0013, 0566` 

sort file2 : $ `0013, 0025, 0566`
```

In that case, one way is to replace the comma (and the space after comma) with a new line first:

```
sed 's/, /\
/g' file1
```

and then sort the result (and then compare).

Here is the bash file that I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

sed 's/, /\
/g' file1 > file1_formatted

sed 's/, /\
/g' file2 > file2_formatted

sort file1_formatted > file1_sorted
sort file2_formatted > file2_sorted

comm -3  file1_sorted file2_sorted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff`, or you could use `comm` on sorted files.  Assuming you have Bash with [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), then:

```
comm <(sort test1.csv) <(sort test2.csv)
```

This will list the lines only in file 1 unindented, those only in file 2 indented by one tab, and those in both indented by two tabs.  You can control which 'columns' are shown by suppressing those you don't want. For example, to show only the lines that are in one file but not the other, use `-3` to suppress the third column:

```
comm -3 <(sort test1.csv) <(sort test2.csv)
```

To show only the lines found in both files (the common lines), suppress column 1 and 2 with:

```
comm -12 <(sort test1.csv) <(sort test2.csv)
```

Comment: Hi, if its a numeric data as I have posted.?

Comment: @user2647888: See my other [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167957/how-to-compare-these-two-files-in-unix/24168142#comment37301817_24167985).  No problem.

Comment: Are you sure there's no problem? I seem to recall `comm` complaining about some numerically sorted files since `comm` doesn't have all of the bells and whistles that `sort` does to specify the sorting order so you know you sorted the files the way you wanted but `comm` doesn't agree that that order is `sorted`.

Comment: @EdMorton: I'm tolerably certain that the plain sort commands shown here and in the 'diff' answer will not cause problems. If you add decorations (options) to the sort commands, you might run into the difficulties you allude too. You're right that `comm` has a very lited understanding of sorted order.